# Failure in using alter table to add partition

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, partitioning, alter-table

I have a table having structure as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `child_table` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `value` int,
    `ref_id` int,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `ref_id` (`ref_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK4E9BF08E940F8C98` FOREIGN KEY (`ref_id`) REFERENCES `parent_table` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

When running statement to add partition, it fails and show the error:

```
ERROR 1217: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `learning`.`child_table`  PARTITION BY HASH(ref_id) PARTITIONS 10
```

So I remove the foreign constraint with parent_table, then run again. It still fails and show the same error.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `child_table` has no key that is a foreign key on another table?

Comment: No, it has only one foreign key. And I've removed it completely after the first failed message.

Comment: I don't mean a foreign key on `child_table` I mean a foreign key on another table that links to `child_table`

Comment: Ok, thank you. Sorry about that. I pass that error, another one comes. But I think I can resolve it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but for people that fall here from looking for this problem, since its the first Google result:

#### MySQL does not support foreign keys on partitioned tables.

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html)

> **Foreign keys not supported for partitioned InnoDB tables.**  Partitioned tables using the InnoDB storage engine do not support foreign keys. More specifically, this means that the following two statements are true:
>
> 1. No definition of an InnoDB table employing user-defined partitioning may contain foreign key references; no InnoDB table whose definition contains foreign key references may be partitioned.
> 2. No InnoDB table definition may contain a foreign key reference to a user-partitioned table; no InnoDB table with user-defined partitioning may contain columns referenced by foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

The error is referring to a foreign key on another table that *references* `child_table`.  You need to find and remove the foreign key from *that* table, not necessarily `child_table`.  You could also try running `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` first.

Comment: I try to `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` but it does not work. I have to remove all foreign keys which reference to `child_table`